Problem with Matrix Multiplication in OpenGL Shader Program
I’m currently studying OpenGL with ModernGL. I can render a red cube without any issues using the vertices below and assigning them to a shader program:
Red Cube Rendered
Here’s the code I used to generate the vertex data:
red cube rendered
def get_vertex_data(self):
    vertices = [(-1, -1, 1),
                   (1, -1, 1),
                   (1, 1, 1),
                   (-1, 1, 1),
                   (-1, 1, -1),
                   (-1, -1, -1),
                   (1, -1, -1),
                   (1, 1, -1),]
      
    indices = [(0, 2, 3),(0, 1, 2),
                (1, 7, 2),(1, 6, 7),
                (6, 5, 4),(4, 7, 6),
                (3, 4, 5),(3, 5, 0),
                (3, 7, 4),(3, 2, 7),
                (0, 6, 1),(0, 5, 6),]
        
    vertex_data = self.get_data(vertices, indices)
        
    print(f'Vertex data = \n {vertex_data}')
    return vertex_data


@staticmethod
def get_data(vertices, indices):
    data = [vertices[ind] for triangle in indices for ind in triangle]
    return np.array(data, dtype='f4')

The shader code:
 
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 ini_position;

void main() {

    gl_Position =vec4(ini_position.xy, ini_position.z, 1.0);
}



However, when I multiply the vertices by the identity matrix, the cube disappears.
Here’s the identity matrix from the matrix.py file:
the default clear color, blue
Identity Matrix from matrix.py file

@staticmethod
def mIdentity():
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1],]).astype('float32')
    


I create an identity matrix shader program like this:
self.shaderProgram['identityMatrix'].write(self.camera.m_identity)


and here is the updated shader program.
 
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 ini_position;
uniform mat4 identityMatrix;
void main() {

    gl_Position = identityMatrix * vec4(ini_position.xy, ini_position.z, 1.0);
}



when I run the app we can check some prints outputs:
shaderProgram["ini_position"] =  <Attribute: 0>
shaderProgram["identityMatrix"] =  <Uniform: 0>
identity matrix value =
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
shaderProgram["ini_position"] =  <Attribute: 0>
Vertex data =
[[-1. -1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
[-1.  1.  1.]
[-1. -1.  1.]
[ 1. -1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
[ 1. -1.  1.]
[ 1.  1. -1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
[ 1. -1.  1.]
[ 1. -1. -1.]
[ 1.  1. -1.]
[ 1. -1. -1.]
[-1. -1. -1.]
[-1.  1. -1.]
[-1.  1. -1.]
[ 1.  1. -1.]
[ 1. -1. -1.]
[-1.  1.  1.]
[-1.  1. -1.]
[-1. -1. -1.]
[-1.  1.  1.]
[-1. -1. -1.]
[-1. -1.  1.]
[-1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1. -1.]
[-1.  1. -1.]
[-1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1. -1.]
[-1. -1.  1.]
[ 1. -1. -1.]
[ 1. -1.  1.]
[-1. -1.  1.]
[-1. -1. -1.]
[ 1. -1. -1.]]
vao created: <moderngl.VertexArray object at 0x000001FB688C5880>      
VAO, VBO AND SHADER PROGRAM RELEASED


I tried to use other matrices like projection or translation matrices, and none of them seem to work properly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Try giving a linear array, rather than an array of arrays as your matrix.

Yesterday, I added the flatten function, but the issue persists. The cube continues to render red when not using matrix multiplication. However, when the matrix is applied, the cube disappears again.

try reversing the order of multiplication by swapping the vertex position and the matrix
gl_Position =vec4(ini_position.xy, ini_position.z, 1.0) * identityMatrix;
}

if that didn't work
try checking that the identity matrix is sent properly
by sending the matrix to the fragment shader then
putting the color to identityMatrix[0]
and you should see a red color
and repeat that for 1 and 2
and you should see green then blue
if that didn't happen then there's a problem with the identity matrix being sent to the GPU

The multiplication order doesn't matter in that case, it's the same as transposing the matrix, which doesn't change the diagonal.

no, it's not guaranteed that the transpose of the identity matrix that this guy is sending to the GPU is actually a identity matrix, so that it's transpose is the same as it
